# How to send arbitrary payload with Mojo::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo-useragent

I'm trying to use [`Mojo::UserAgent`](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent) to access the eBay API.

One of the options is to use API requests with an XML payload, but I have had no success doing it with `Mojo::UserAgent`. I didn't find any options for the `$ua->post` method.

I also tried

```
my $tx = $ua->build_tx(POST => $ebay_api_url => $headers);
$tx->req->body($xml_body);
my $res = $ua->start($tx)->res->json;
```

with no success. The XML body is not set for the request.

What do I need to do to achieve the desired result?

I know about the possibility of using JSON requests, but that is a reserve plan.

Comment: did you finally find the solution? Same problem here, except in this case I already have created the JSON

Answer (score 1):

Try to post your $xml_body like so:

```
my $tx = $ua->post($ebay_api_url => form => $xml_body);
```

Comment: I tried, no results, there must be a HASH after 'form =>', but I have a string with XML

Comment: @NikitaTropin so `$ua->post($ebay_api_url => $xml_body);` wouldn't work either?

Comment: No, it's not. `Malformed JSON: Expected string, array, object, number, boolean or null at line 0, offset 0 at /home/nikita/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.3/lib/site_perl/5.20.3/Mojo/Message.pm line 140`. I'm passing string in $xml_body btw.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want (2nd example in [post doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent#post)):

```
my $tx = $ua->post($ebay_api_url => {Accept => '*/*'} => $xml_body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue like yours but later I realized that the problem was with the xml data. Please ensure that you do not have any trailing or leading white spaces in your $xml_body. This works:

```
   my $tx = $ua->post($ebay_api_url => $headers => $xml_body);
```

[Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) and [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) is awesome and light.